# Run application as Console app with args passed, otherwise run as Win Form app

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I have an application, that I want to run like this:

- if args sent - I want it to behave as console application
- if args not sent - I want it to run as windows forms application

When I set output type to console and when args not detected I'm enabling visual styles and running. It works great, except the console window opens/closes quickly and that really bothers me. Is there a way to not have the console window appear?I'm looking for a way to not create it at all.

Comment: I'd do it the other way round, make it a WinForms app, because you get into code before anything is created (in your `main` function in `program.cs`).

Comment: http://www.rootsilver.com/2007/08/how-to-create-a-consolewindow

Comment: can you split your into three executables ? One for the windows app, one for the console app and another to bootsrap one of the two ? Obviously, you'll have to create a class library for your engine.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it the other way round, make it a WinForms app, because you get into code before anything is created (in your main function in program.cs).

See this link: http://www.rootsilver.com/2007/08/how-to-create-a-consolewindow

Comment: it looks like the link above is broken.  Do you have the content elsewhere you could share?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a Windows.Forms application
2. Add an external function

   ```
   [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport( "kernel32.dll" )]
   private static extern bool AllocConsole();
   ```
3. In the main method of your application:

   ```
   if ( windows_app )
   {
     Application.EnableVisualStyles(); 
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
     Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
   else
   { 
       AllocConsole();
       Console.WriteLine( "foo" );
   }
   ```

Comment: The challenge here is that AllocConsole() appears to create a new console window rather than using the console that you run the app from.  "foo" would appear in the new window, which immediately disappears as the app exits from it's command line invocation.